# Visualizing a point cloud previously stored in an array

Tags: ros, rviz, pcl, array, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'd like to visualize a point cloud by using rviz. The points' coordinates were previously stored in an array that contains the x-, y- and z-coordinates of each point within a struct data type. I tried to store this data in the corresponding ~.x, ~.y, ~.z members of a pcl::PointXYZ object. However, I am not sure if this works and if so, how to make it to the publication of this cloud, so I can see something on rviz.
It would be great if someone could tell how this works.
Kevin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44873/visualizing-a-point-cloud-previously-stored-in-an-array/) by [tordalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3289/tordalk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#Publishing_point_clouds) to find some example code.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0